# FireBase - angularfire setting object key as variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using firebase(angularfire) in my angularjs app to store and process my message system but can't seem to figure out how to replicate the example data from the firebase docs

```
 // room members are easily accessible (or restricted)
      // we also store these by room ID
      "members": {
        // we'll talk about indices like this below
        "one": {
          "mchen": true,
          "hmadi": true
        }
      }
```

Here the `members.one` contains the user name as a key and I am trying to do this for my data as well but can't seem to figure out a solution.

The members portion of my firebase data is like so:

`members { one: { } }`

I have two variables set in the $scope.

```
user_name = kep; //person chatting with name
sender_name = pek; //current user name
```

So I want to use the set function to insert data into `members.one` or in this case `members.user_name + ':' + sender_name` but where I am having trouble is how to actually insert the data without creating a parent object.

```
ref.child('members').child(user_name + ':' + sender_name).set({
    user_name: true, sender_name: true
 });
```

The problem arises when I try to pass user_name and sender_name into the set() function below is the result it gets.

```
members { "kep:pek": { user_name: true, sender_name: true }}
```

where as I want it to be:

```
members { "kep:pek": { kep: true, pek: true }}
```

If I put user_name and sender_name into an object and then run the set() function with the object passed it will create the following structure which is not what I am looking for:

```
members { "kep:pek": { newObject: { kep: true, pek: true }}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase team member here.

The Firebase Database is a just a JSON document.

So let's say you want to structure your data this way:

```
{
  "members" : {
    "kep:pek" : {
      "kep" : true,
      "pek" : true
    }
  }
}
```

A custom key is created by using the `.child()` method, or by creating a key in the JavaScript Object.

[**JSBin Demo**](http://jsbin.com/xunohajawu/edit?js,output)

```
var rootRef = new Firebase('<my-firebase-app>');
var membersRef = rootRef.child('members');
var user_name = 'kep';
var sender_name = 'pek';
// child object to store custom keys
var objectToSave = {};
// set keys in [] syntax
objectToSave[user_name] = true;
objectToSave[sender_name] = true;
// use .child() with a formatted string to save the object
membersRef.child(user_name + ':' + sender_name).set(objectToSave);
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for taking the time to help. I was trying to do the above but it is inserting as an object and not just key value pairs. It insert like so `members.one.obj { user_name: true }` and not `members.one { user_name: true }` The users are being generated on click (chat rooms) and thats why the user_name and sender_name need to be passed

Comment: Anywhere where you need a key you can use `.child()`, and then set the dat a needed at that path. At the end of the day everything is just one JSON object. I updated my answer to represent that.

Comment: When I insert using the above it creates the following structure: `members: { one: { objectToSave: { "mchen": true } } }` where as I want `members: { one: {  "mchen": true } }` the only problem I keep running into is that when inserting like my second example how do I pass user_name to show up as mchen? - @David East

Comment: I'm confused now. In your first comment you said didn't want `members.one { user_name: true }` and now you're saying that's what you want. Regardless of what you want though, it's all just a key/value store. Calling `.child(keyName)` with a key name will get you what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I re-worded my question maybe it makes more sense now ?

Comment: I updated my answer and also provided a demo. It should work for you now.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help that produces the correct results. Cheers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96843/discussion-between-spade-and-david-east).